# No scroll in div using relative margins

Tags: html, css, scroll

Basically I am echoing some stuff with PHP, the content extends beyond the window but there is no scrollbar whatsoever. I tried using `overflow: scroll;` but it doesn't work.

Here's full site code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['commented']))
        unset($_SESSION['secretid']);

    unset($_SESSION['commented']);
 ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Confession | Pokaż sekret</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("body").removeClass("preload");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h3>Losowy sekret:</h3>
        <?php 
            include_once("db.php");

            $connection = @new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM secrets";
            $result = @$connection->query($query);
            $rows = $result->num_rows;

            if ($rows == 0)
                echo '<div id="view">Brak sekretów w bazie danych!</div><br />';
            else
            {
                /* Get the lowest id */
                $query = "SELECT id FROM secrets ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
                $result = @$connection->query($query);
                $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $min = $data['id'];

                /* Get the highest id */
                $query = "SELECT id FROM secrets ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                $result = @$connection->query($query);
                $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $max = $data['id'];

                /* Select a random row */
                if (!isset($_SESSION['secretid']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['secretid'] = RAND($min, $max);

                    if ($rows > 1)
                        while ($_SESSION['secretid'] == $_SESSION['lastid'])
                            $_SESSION['secretid'] = RAND($min, $max);

                    $_SESSION['lastid'] = $_SESSION['secretid'];
                }

                $rand = $_SESSION['secretid'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM secrets WHERE id = '$rand' LIMIT 1";
                $result = @$connection->query($query);
                $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

                echo '<div id="view">'.$data['secret'].'</div>';
                echo '<h3>Komentarze:</h3>';

                $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE secret = '$rand'";
                $result = @$connection->query($query);
                $rows = $result->num_rows;

                if ($rows == 0)
                    echo '<div id="view">Brak komentarzy do wyświetlenia</div>';
                else
                {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
                    { 
                        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

                        for ($j = 0; $j < 74; $j++)
                        { 
                            echo '-';
                        }
                        echo '<br /><div id="view">'.$data['comment'].'</div>';     
                    }

                    for ($i = 0; $i < 74; $i++)
                    { 
                        echo '-';
                    }
                }

                echo "<h3>Napisz komentarz<br />(max 100 znaków):</h3>
                <form style='display: inline;' id='shareform' method='post' action='comment.php'>
                    <textarea name='comment' style='resize: none;' cols='41' rows='5' maxlength='100'></textarea><br />
                    <a href='javascript:{}' onclick='document.getElementById(\"shareform\").submit(); return false;'>Skomentuj</a>
                </form><br /><br />";
            }

            $connection->close();
         ?>

        <a href="view_secret.php">Następny sekret</a>
        <a href="index.php">Powrót</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I write everything manually the scroll bar shows up like normal.
Oh, and here's a screenshot of how it actually looks:
[image]

@edit: CSS

```
body {
    background: url("../img/crossed_stripes.png");
    font-family: "Oxygen", verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.preload * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}

#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.secret {
    width: 100%;
}

#view {
    color: #FF5555;
}

a, a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted;
}

a:hover {
    color: #777777;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
}

textarea {
    background-color: #222222;
    font-family: "Oxygen", verdana;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #999999;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 27px;
}
```

Comment: What's in your stylesheet? I assume you have some `overflow:hidden` there

Comment: Nope. I edited the question so you can see.

Comment: Several elements have the same ID. That's no valid HTML. Use classes for this,

Comment: Oh ok. Didn't fix it tho, still no scroll bar.

Comment: is this live? can we see the url?

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. It's strictly a CSS styling problem. So I've edited the tags and title of the question to clarify for others looking at the question. Please try reducing your issue to a reproducible [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) just focusing on the html/css code that creates the problem with actual sample data rather than including all of the useless PHP cruft that isn't relevant to this problem. You'll get much more useful answers this way from folks skilled at CSS.

Comment: to get the `overflow:scroll`, you need to set the height, set the `height` for example, `300px` or any what you want, that's it; it will apply `overflow: scroll`, set the height of your `#wrapper`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have block elements (*i.e. the `#view` divs*) inside of a fixed block element. So the relative `top` and `left` style of the `#wrapper` div forces those block elements to be relatively positioned. This won't ever let your scroll within the div itself or span the page scroll in rendering.

Instead you should consider just positioning the `wrapper` div with a fixed `top` say `20px` and the page should behave as you expect it to. Unfortunately centering the div vertically on the page relative to its own height is not ideal in CSS. That's why front-end frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) have an [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) method in javascript. I don't think that's what you actually want though. I think you're trying to center the div vertically and horizontally on the page, but the div does not have a fixed size so this is not exactly going to work out very well for you when the div expands dynamically as you can see. Just set a fixed top margin instead to avoid this problem altogether and don't worry so much about centering it vertically.